# Seggregating the output of a query

Tags: oracle

My question might seem weird. But I need to know whether we can identify and seggregate the rows fetched from particular table in a query, which is formed by joining tables.

Please refer the below query if I am you are not clear with my question.

My requirement is to know the rows fetched from table 'rel' alone in the query.

```
SELECT rel.*
FROM rel,  C
WHERE rel.col1  = C.col1
AND C.col1 NOT IN (SELECT R.col1 FROM R WHERE R.col2 = 'MN')
AND rel.col2= 'MN'
AND rel.col3= 'MN'
AND c.col2  ='MN';
```

Thanks,
Savitha

Comment: Your question does not make sense, yet. What do you mean by a "row fetched from a particular table in a query"?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are performing an INNER JOIN by using the comparison in the WHERE clause, all your records, by definition, are coming from the rel table.